# Python - assigning digits of a number to variables

Tags: python-3.x

How do i input a three digit number from the user and assign 3 different variables to the three digits:

```
>>> Numbers = int(input("Enter a 3 digit number : "))
Enter a 3 digit number : 411
```

now i want to assign the digits 4 to say x, 1 to y and 1 to z.
Any tips?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign to different variables?

Comment: I disagree that this simple Q is a duplicate of a complex Q about ISBN.  Anyway, `x, y, z = str(Numbers)` answers this Q -- though I can only post it as a comment unless and until I can get this Q reopened!-)